# I got "+6 Serial voting was reversed" - what does it mean?

Tags: support, serial-voting

From other questions on meta i guestimated that the SO system controlls if one user goes over multiple answers of another user and up/downvotes them - kindof a step to stop harassing childish behaviour.

Sorry for 2 questions:

- I did not find the descriptive text for Serial voting, Point me to it?
- The +6 means someone downvoted me multiple times and I got some points "back" ?

Edit:
I found this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed
which worded headline slightly differs (the "URL" fits) - maybe adapt the headline?

> Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says
>   **"voting corrected"?**

Edit2:
Did a Change request here: [Change the title of https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed to match "serial-voting-reversed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359258/7505395)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algorithm which defines the line for serial voting is not publicly available to prevent users from gaming it.

More than likely, pure speculation here since the algorithm is private, someone hit you with 3 downvotes, all in a small time frame, and the script caught it when it runs (some time between UTC datelines). When it overturned the votes, you got +6 reputation.

Comment: Thanks. I am not after trade secrets (the algorythm) - I was looking where it is documented that this Feature exists - just did not find it via site search, found it (similar wording) here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed - edited my question.

Comment: Could it also mean that I have accidentally serial voted and those votes were undone? I can't find several downvotes on my stuff.

Comment: I'm glad this algorithm exists: I received six downvotes in a small period of time, I wondered what I had done in order to piss someone of that bad but the algorithm corrected that serial downvoting behaviour.

Comment: Something very strange happened to me yesterday: I (apparently) got 9 upvotes, on various answers/questions by me, a couple of them being voted up twice. Then this algorithm apparently identified this and did "serial voting was reversed", to do -90 at the end of the day. Why would a person do this to my rep? It even suggests that whoever it is is operating more than one account. Should I be flattered? I'm more inclined to be weirded out.