# Change the title of https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed to match "serial-voting-reversed"

Tags: feature-request, help-center, serial-voting

I think we should Change the title of the help page https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

from

> Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?

to

> Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "serial voting reversed"?

to match the message to user more closely.

At least I was midly confused by the voting message (see [I got "+6 Serial voting was reversed" - what does it mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359253/7505395)) *Serial voting reversed* - as I haden't stumbled opon that term in the docs regarding votings.

Edit: Screenshot:

[image: Popup on recent inbox messages]

If I click the link I get redirected to my users "?tab=Reputation". If I then click the graphics today's bar, I get the seperate items that lead to that days summary voting and that then shows

> Voting corrected ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed))

So what got me confused was the wording in the screenshot.

Almost seems to be a "me" problem...

Comment: Well, [your voting page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner?tab=reputation) does say "voting corrected" on it. Perhaps the message you received in your inbox was different?

Comment: @TravisJ thanks for pointing that out - it is worded differently in the inbox then the detailed view for this day. Editet screenshot in. The one on detailed page even has the link to the relevant page... I am thinking about retracting this request...

Comment: No need to retract it, the wording should be the same everywhere to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: Yeah we need to fix this in the achievements dialog at some point. The wording was changed to "voting corrected" because it made it sound less like the user did something wrong and more just a natural way of correcting misbehavior of someone else, or something like that.